# .ipa file cannot install in ios devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, ipa

I have build an .ipa file from xcode12 through app store distribution. I didn't upload it to app store instead I save it to my disk. The .ipa file was inside a folder. I have uploaded the .ipa file to **https://www.iphonecake.com**  and shared to my Iphone. It showes installing after that the error comes like:
[image: check the screen shot]

any one have any idea on what might have caused this. Please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple cancelled all tweaked apps’ certificates starting with iOS 14, so devices can't manage the download of .ipa files and it doesn’t have a proper solution yet. You can downgrade your phone to iOS 13 and it will work.

Comment: will exporting the .ipa file in ad-hoc for registered devices work?